# If I don't migrate my iOS apps from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have a lot of iOS apps that are using Fabric/Crashlytics. Will these apps continue to work even if I don't migrate from Fabric to Firebase? Also, Does migration from Fabric to Firebase requires app update on Apple Store?

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge, **NO**, You don't need migration for Apple Store.

But You need migration for why you developed this feature. Yes, Fabric Apis' will work even without migration. But the Fabric console won't work from the mentioned date. So You should migrate to Firebase else you can't see reports in Fabric.

Comment: If reports can't be accessed, why should the API continue to work? For example, why keep `fabric.io` endpoints as the API when instead it would be something like `appid.firebase.io`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to migrate your apps from Fabric to Firebase. So there will be no change in your app so no need to uploaded app again on Apple Store.

From March 2020, Fabric will be deprecated and probably it is not going to work and then you have to migrate to Firebase.

[image]

Comment: So, what exactly I need to do to follow this Fabric to Firebase process??